# How does the "Double damage in combat" trait work for the Mantis crew in FTL

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Its unclear as to whether this trait means that a subsystem manned by a Mantis crew member causes double damage to the subsystem (when damage is received) or to the enemy (when damage is dealt).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By "combat", they mean man-to-man combat, not ship-to-ship combat.  Basically, Mantes make good raiding parties or security guards.

Comment: Hand-to-hand combat? Thanks that clears it up.

Comment: Hand-to-hand and gun-to-face, specifically.  :-)

Comment: Oh, and Mantes is the plural of Mantis.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Awesome D:

Comment: Actually, rocks make better security guards because they can take way more punishment (also, you can set the section of the ship you're fighting in on fire and they won't care)

Comment: @Shadur - the only problem with rocks is that a boarding party can run rings around them

Comment: @Robotnik - if you haven't upgraded to blast doors you deserve your fate! ;-)

Comment: @Shaderach - oh don't worry, my doors are upgraded :P. I meant by the time my rock crewmen actually walk the length of the ship to get to the enemy boarding party, either my other crew have taken care of it, they've suffocated (I'm sadistic like that) or they've teleported away again.

Comment: @BlackVegetable The "double damage" stated by the game is incorrect; Mantes only get a 50% bonus to combat damage, which exactly cancels out the Rock's bonus health.  A rock can kill a mantis in single combat if it gets any sort of advantage at all (including already being in the room when the mantis walks in, for a free shot).

Comment: @Brilliand Nope you are correct.  I couldn't remember where I posted this misinformation.  I was wrong for exactly the reason you mentioned.  The trouble is whether the skill mastery bonuses are additive or multiplicative, but I have a question for that posted already...